# How to know who is an attacker in byzantine broadcast?

Tags: protocol-design

2 requirements of Byzantine broadcast (consistency and validity) only state honest node should output certain bit without mentioning what should malicious nodes do.

How do we know the identity of each node? 
Could I distinguish honest and malicious node by checking the majority of vote (honest nodes is majority) assuming success?

**Context**
Consistency: If two honest nodes output b and b' respectively, then b = b'.
Validity: If the sender is honest and receives the input bit b, then all honest nodes should output b. [P12, 1]

**Reference** 
[1]Fundations of Distributed Consensus and Blockchains, Elaine Shi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Byzantine broadcast definition only requires consistency and validity, it does not require fault localization. So in general you cannot tell whether a node is malicious or not unless your specific Byzantine broadcast protocol supports this feature.

Additionally, in general you cannot easily check the majority of the vote to figure out which nodes are malicious since there does not exist a single trusted entity that can do the check. You'd need to run more Byzantine broadcast protocols to do this check.

Comment: If we don't know the identity, does it mean we don't know the agreement result is made by malicious or honest parties either? 
In other words, we can only state the result would be correct under #(malicious node) < #(totol node)/3, but we don't actually know if it's correct?

Comment: The answer will depend on what you mean by correct. A correct Byzantine broadcast protocol will have the consistency and validity property, so I will assume correct means these two properties hold. So this only guarantees that honest nodes have consistent results. From the view of an honest node, and you output some bit $b$, then you know all other honest nodes have the same output. If there are $2n/3$ honest nodes then you know they all output the same bit $b$. But honest nodes do not know whether the sender is honest.

Comment: Also, you might get more insightful answers if you ask consensus questions on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ since that's traditionally a CS field.